# submit form only by click on form and not the from fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
    document.getElementById("searhForm").onclick = function()
    {
        alert();
        //document.getElementById("searhForm").submit();
    }
```

```css
#searhForm
{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <form method="post"  action="#" id="searhForm" >
            <input class="form-control" type="search" id="query" placeholder="Search!" >
        </form>
```

I want to trigger alert() when user click anywhere on the form. but when user click the text-field it should simply let the user write and alert() should not be triggered

Comment: If JQuery is actually an option you could check ID/classes/etc on the clicked element by using event.target. https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the `nodeName` before triggering the alert

```js
 document.getElementById("searhForm").onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
        alert();
      }
    }
```

```css
  #searhForm {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
 <form method="post" action="#" id="searhForm">
    <input class="form-control" type="search" id="query" placeholder="Search!">
  </form>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check it. If it doesn't work, let me know.

```
document.getElementById("searhForm").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
var a = document.getElementById("query");
if(e.target != a) {
        alert();
        //document.getElementById("searhForm").submit();
}
});
```